# Google Ads have just stopped loading? getting JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_getSdkConstants is not defined

Tags: android, admob

I am working on an application in which I have to show ads. Ads were working just fine when I placed them. After a week or so, they just stopped loading. Checking the Log cat revealed me I am getting following exception:

```
JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_getSdkConstants is not defined (http://media.admob.com/:1)
```

I don't know what has happened suddenly. It was working great on 4.x Android OS. but now it is not. Any help how to solve the issue is appreciated.

Following is my code I am using in xml:

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adUnitId="My ID"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

In the manifest I have:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" 
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: I just got this during a momentary loss of internet connection. Does it appear constantly?

Comment: @WindRider ... No, it did not last forever. It was as per my observation due to a weak internet connection. after few days ads were displaying fine.